# Second bounty awarded on same answer overrides the first in the display

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, information-display

One picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

As you can see in the [revisions of the relevant question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/61704/revisions), the first bounty (of 50 rep) was started by **James** in **Aug 12** but the second bounty "overwrites" this.

Edit: same problem in reverse direction - [offered bounties of Rob](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132734/rob-hruska?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date shown there is the **last activity date** of the question (as with all other question lists on the profile), it isn't related to the bounty.